# Using/Calling a cursor in another cursor - PL/Sql

Tags: function, plsql, database-cursor

I have a function with a cursor which returns an ID. I need to get some fields in another cursor using this ID result from the first cursor.

So my first cursor is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function get_id(id number) 

CURSOR child_id
   IS
       SELECT table1_id
            FROM table1,child
              WHERE child_id = id
          AND table1_id = child_chld_id;
```

Ideally my second cursor should be:

```
cursor grandchild_id
is
select table1_id from table1,child
where child_id = (return value of id from cursor child_id)
and table1_id = child_chld_id;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: @Anne - Thanks for editing. I never can figure how to do it!!

Comment: Basically: Paste code, select code, click the `{}` button and make sure the line above is empty. Hope that helps!

Comment: Why don't you combine them into one query? It will very probably be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Cursors can accept parameters:

```
cursor grandchild_id(other_child_id number)
is
select table1_id from table1,child
where child_id = grandchild_id.other_child_id
and table1_id = child_chld_id;
```

Whenever you open the `grandchild_id` cursor, simply pass the appropriate value as an argument:

```
grandchild_id(the_value_you_obtained_from_the_first_cursor)
```

Comment: I will be using this in Oracle discoverer where it will run for all the ids in the database...how will it work in that case? Thanks for answering

Comment: @Cindy: I do not know. You may want to edit your question to include the fact that you're using Discoverer.